# What does 「自分の生きている姿勢」 mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

I am reading Osamu Dazai's 「人間失格」.

> また、犯人意識、という言葉もあります。自分は、この人間の世の中に於いて、一生その意識に苦しめられながらも、しかし、それは自分の糟糠の妻の如き好伴侶で、そいつと二人きりで侘びしく遊びたわむれているというのも、**自分の生きている姿勢**の一つだったかも知れないし...

When I read this sentence as a whole, I think 姿勢 means attitude, way of thinking etc., but when I read the phrase 「自分の生きている姿勢」, without the context of the entire sentence, it does not make sense.

Here are the possible meanings I can think of for 「自分の生きている姿勢」

- my living posture ? (this sounds weird)
- the way of thinking I am living with ?

Why is 生きている used with in this sentence ? What exactly does 「生きている姿勢」mean here ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 姿勢 (literally "stance") refers to a "way" of doing something, and 自分の生きている姿勢 is roughly the same as 自分の生き方 or "my way of living".

> 自分の生きている姿勢の一つだったかも知れないし…
>   (living a life embracing the sense of guilt) may have been one of the (possible) ways of my life, and ...

Comment: Thank you! It makes a lot more sense now.